# useMutation not updating the useQuery data (Tanstack Query)

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I following the official Tanstack Query [useMutation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/guides/updates-from-mutation-responses) docs to update my products after adding a new product:

**ProductsPage.tsx**

```
const { data, isError, isPending, error } = useQuery<
  FetchResponse<'products'>,
  Error
>({ queryKey: ['products'], queryFn: fetchProductsMock });

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('useEffect data:', data);
  if (data?.products) {
    setProducts(data?.products);
  }
}, [data]);
```

**addProductModal.tsx**

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient();

const mutation = useMutation({
  mutationFn: createProductMock,
  onSuccess: (data) => {
    console.log('useMutation data:', data);
    queryClient.setQueryData<StringRecord[]>(
      ['products'],
      (oldProducts = []) => {
        return [...oldProducts, data];
      },
    );
  },
});

function handleSubmit(values: any) {
  mutation.mutate(values);
  form.reset();
  setIsOpen(false);
}
```

`console.log('useMutation data:', data);` logs the new data, so I know the `useMutation` part was successful. However, `console.log('useEffect data:', data);` doesn't log anything, so I know `useQuery` didn't run again with the new data.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but what I see in first place is that you update your cache incorrectly. Your `useQuery` returns an object that has `products` property and your `setQueryData` returns an array. It should be same as the return type of the `useQuery` (object)

```
queryClient.setQueryData<StringRecord[]>(
  ['products'],
  (oldData) => {
    if (!oldData) return
    return {...oldData, products: [...oldData.products, data]};
  },
);
```

is the component that uses your useQuery still mounted? If not - it won't display anything.